# Maximum number of connections per database on a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-connection

Is there a maximum number of connections per database level on a SQL Server?

At the minute I am aware the [max number connections per SQL Server instance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5766/managing-maximum-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-sql-server/) defaults to 0, which is `32,767`.

But is the number of connections restricted at the database level too?

Comment: No, there is no database-level limit. I'm curious as to the reason for your question.

Comment: More curiosity.  There are `AppPools` in dotnet applications which have a finite size.  I just wondered if it was restricted at a database level too.